Undefined reference when building with f2py and scikit-build-core
I have a Python package with a Fortran 90 extension. Originally, I used distutils and f2py to build the extension, but since that was deprecated I switched to using scikit-build with cmake and f2py. That was working, but has more recently started to fail for some users (I suspect due to some setuptools deprecations). I'm trying to switch to scikit-build-core (see here), which avoids using setuptools altogether, but I'm now seeing an error I can't quite understand.
I've written my CMakeLists.txt like so, based on the example on the scikit-build-core docs:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.2...3.29)
project(${SKBUILD_PROJECT_NAME} LANGUAGES C Fortran)

find_package(
  Python
  COMPONENTS Interpreter Development.Module NumPy
  REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

# F2PY headers
execute_process(
  COMMAND "${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}" -c
          "import numpy.f2py; print(numpy.f2py.get_include())"
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE F2PY_INCLUDE_DIR
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

add_library(fortranobject OBJECT "${F2PY_INCLUDE_DIR}/fortranobject.c")
target_link_libraries(fortranobject PUBLIC Python::NumPy)
target_include_directories(fortranobject PUBLIC "${F2PY_INCLUDE_DIR}")
set_property(TARGET fortranobject PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

set(f2py_module_name "calc11")
set(fortran_src_file "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/calc11/src/calc11.f90")
set(generated_module_file ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${f2py_module_name}${PYTHON_EXTENSION_MODULE_SUFFIX})

# Generate param11.in file in cmake build directory
file(READ ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/calc11/src/param11.i.in CONTENTS)
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/calc11/src/param11.i ${CONTENTS})

# This is the path with all of the fortran code, which gets concatenated into a single file "calc11.f90"
add_subdirectory(calc11)

# Include all the include files
file(GLOB includes ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"/calc11/src/*.i")
list(PREPEND includes ${generated_module_file})

# Run f2py to generate extension
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${generated_module_file}
  DEPENDS ${includes}
  VERBATIM
  COMMAND "${Python_EXECUTABLE}" -m numpy.f2py
          "${fortran_src_file}" -m ${f2py_module_name} --lower)

python_add_library(${f2py_module_name} MODULE "${fortran_src_file}" WITH_SOABI)
target_link_libraries(${f2py_module_name} PRIVATE fortranobject)

install(TARGETS ${f2py_module_name} DESTINATION ${SKBUILD_PROJECT_NAME})

My understanding is that f2py needs the fortranobject library to build things correctly, but it's only there because it's in the example code.
When I compile the extension, I get this error from the linker:
 [5/5] Linking Fortran shared module calc11.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
      FAILED: calc11.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
      : && /usr/bin/gfortran -fPIC -O3 -DNDEBUG -O3   -shared  -o calc11.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so CMakeFiles/fortranobject.dir/tmp/pip-build-env-ebv97u47/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c.o CMakeFiles/calc11.dir/calc11/src/calc11.f90.o   && :
      /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/fortranobject.dir/tmp/pip-build-env-ebv97u47/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c.o: in function `get_elsize':
      fortranobject.c:(.text+0x240): undefined reference to `_npy_f2py_ARRAY_API'
      /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/fortranobject.dir/tmp/pip-build-env-ebv97u47/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `_npy_f2py_ARRAY_API' can not be used when making a shared object
      /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value


i.e., there's no "_npy_f2py_ARRAY_API" in the fortranobject library.
I was able to get the extension module to compile before with an older version of numpy (1.23), but then when I imported it it still gave me the error that _npy_f2py_ARRAY_API was undefined.
The problem seems to be coming from the target_link_libraries command, because it builds if I leave that out. However, the compiled module errors in that case (it clearly needs to be linked to fortranobject).

Use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran tags. Always follow the instructions displayed when adding a tag.

I was able to resolve this. The trouble seems to be that the original scikit-build with distutils did a lot on its own to include necessary f2py libraries, and I wasn't including the right.
The call to f2py, and subsequent code adding the library and linking it, should be this:
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT calc11module.c calc11-f2pywrappers.f calc11-f2pywrappers2.f90
  DEPENDS ${includes}
  VERBATIM
  COMMAND "${Python_EXECUTABLE}" -m numpy.f2py
          "${fortran_src_file}" -m ${f2py_module_name} --lower
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)

python_add_library(
        ${f2py_module_name}
       MODULE
       "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/calc11-f2pywrappers2.f90"
       "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/calc11-f2pywrappers.f"
       "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/calc11module.c"
       "${fortran_src_file}"
       WITH_SOABI)
target_link_libraries(${f2py_module_name} PRIVATE fortranobject)


The "f2pywrapper" files provide the necessary API for Python functions. This links correctly, and now it runs.
